# How to draw an overlay using KML on our own app in Android?

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, kml, mobile, android

Repost from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959735/how-to-draw-an-overlay-using-kml-on-our-own-app-in-android)

I want to draw an overlay using KML files, just look like below but on my own app in MapActivity.

[31.kml, display district in Jakarta, Indonesia](http://bit.ly/LDfFhH)
or [the example that I get from googling](http://bit.ly/LatEdV)

I've already tried this code, but it just opens Google map app that already gave me a map with KML overlays.

```
final Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:0,0? q=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32264286/Unggahan/31.kml"));startActivity(myIntent);
```

Is it possible and how can I implement this?